# Two foreign keys with ActiveRecord? [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I have a User class with reference to a Message class. The message class has a `user_id`  (which is the sender) and a `receiver_id`. So in the User class I have

```
  has_many :messages
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
```

and then in the Message class I have

```
  belongs_to :user
```

The first relationship -- via `user_id` -- goes perfectly well. **I haven't the slightest idea what to put in the Message class for the second relationship.** The messages table is built with both `user_id` and `receiver_id`, so the support is there.

**Is this even possible?**

Also, then I'd have no idea how to get to the messages RECEIVED by a user... or the User who received a message :)

[I know that I can work around this by having a sender table and a receiver table and a messages table and maybe a bunch of other tables (a conversations table!), but I'd like to do it like this, for the fun of it. This application will be used for learning only.]

Also important: where would the docs be for this? [This](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_one_through_association_rb.html) is not very helpful.

Comment: Did you try here? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001599

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your User class:

```
has_many :messages
has_many :received_messages, 
         :foreign_key => "receiver_id", :class_name => "Message"
```

In your Message class:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User"


@user = User.first
@user.messages
@user.received_messages
```

Comment: Wow, that's cool: now each Message instance has a user (a User instance) and a receiver (also a User instance). I guess I'll have to go back and change them to a "sender" and receiver :)

Comment: After searching lots of solutions I finally understood this because of your answer. Thanks @assplecake